# Writing to an IC in Python

Tags: python, c, file-io

I have an IC that I am trying to communicate with in Python. I have a working C application, that writes a few bytes and then reads the response, but I can't seem to get the same result in Python.

The IC does respond with the Python code, but it is erroneous suggesting the contents of the write aren't valid.

Here is what I have so far.

Working C implementation:

```
unsigned char buffer[2];
int dev;

dev = open(device_path, O_RDWR);

buffer[0] = 0xB8;
buffer[1] = 0x00;

if (write(*dev, buffer, 2) < 2){
    //error
}

buffer[0] = 0xBE;

if(write(*dev, buffer, 2) < 2){
    //error
}

if(read(*dev, output, 9) < 9){
    //error
}

close(dev);
```

Python:

```
dev = open(device_path, 'r+')
buff = pack('BB', 0xB8, 0x00)
device.write(buff)
buff = pack('BB', 0xBE, 0x00)
device.write(buff)
out = device.read(9)
out = unpack('BBBBBBBBB', out)
print out
dev.close()
```

Working Python:

```
dev = os.open(device_path, os.O_RDWR)
buff = pack('BB', 0xB8, 0x00)
os.write(device, buff)
buff = pack('BB', 0xBE, 0x00)
os.write(device, buff)
out = os.read(device, 9)
out = unpack('BBBBBBBBB', out)
print out
os.close(dev)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `os.open` to open the device to match the C program.

If you insist on using buffered IO, you should at least flush before trying to read.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go. What would be the alternative to buffered IO in Python?